# How do I remove a particular element without deleting its child or data in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have a XML file and it contains multiple `<b>` tags in it. There are specific elements where I do not want the  tags but I want the value or it's child nodes.

For example:

```
<p><b>This is a value</b></p>
<h2><b><i>This is another value</i></b></h2>
<h3><b>This is the last value</b></h3>
```

Here, for `<p>` it is cool, nothing has to be removed. But for `<h2>` and `<h3>`, I want the `<b>` tags removed. So, the final value will be:

```
<p><b>This is a value</b></p>
<h2><i>This is another value</i></h2>
<h3>This is the last value</h3>
```

I know that I can delete the `<b>` tag, save it's value in a variable and again paste it in the element. But is there any other way to do it? I am looking for `linq`.

Comment: `xmlContent.Replace("<b>", string.Empty).Replace("</b>", string.Empty)` ?

Comment: that would remove all the <b> / </b> tags not only what he is asking for @vasily.sib

Comment: @Primo what logic are you hoping for?
the rules you want on when to remove the tag and when to keep are not clear.

Comment: @DenisSchaf it is just a hint, not an answer. You may use `xmlContent.Replace("<h2><b>", "<h2>").Replace("</b></h2>", "</h2>")` the same way. Depends on `xmlContent` variety.

Comment: @DenisSchaf and @vasily.sib - I want something like this `xdoc.Descendants().Where(el => el.Name == "h2" && el.Elements("b").Count() > 0) //Remove the <b> tags but keep its value`.

Comment: I adapted in my answer below to fit your needs

Comment: Have you considered whether you're using the right tool for the job? You want to manipulate the structure of XML in various ways (3 questions so far). Which is a job XSL is great at and you can do it in a *declarative* fashion rather than writing procedural code.

Answer (score 2):

try using this function:

```
    string RemoveTags(string file, string tagToRemove, string parentTag)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(file);
        var remove = doc.Descendants().Where(el => el.Name == tagToRemove && el.Parent.Name == parentTag);
        for (int i = 0; i < remove.Count(); i++)
        {
            remove.ElementAt(i).Parent.Value = remove.ElementAt(i).Value;
        }

        return doc.ToString();
    }
```

It will remove all elements with the tag `tagToRemove` if their parent is  parentTag``while keeping their content

Usage:

```
RemoveTags(@"C:\myFancyXMLDocument.txt", "b", "h2" });
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<frame>
  <p>
    <b>This is a value</b>
  </p>
  <h2>
    <b>
      <i>This is another value</i>
    </b>
  </h2>
  <h3>
    <b>This is the last value</b>
  </h3>
</frame>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<frame>
  <p>
    <b>This is a value</b>
  </p>
  <h2>This is another value</h2>
  <h3>
    <b>This is the last value</b>
  </h3>
</frame>
```

Comment: My `XML` content is in a string variable and this asks for a file, is there a way to give the variable and make the changes? I am parsing my variable `xdoc = XDocument.Parse(filecontent, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);`

Comment: i edited my answer it now takes a string with the xml instead of the path

Comment: It somewhat did. I don't know why, but it is merging the last element with the next one. I mean `<p>This is<br/>a<br/>value.</p>` and `<p>This is another value.</p>` is becoming `<p>This is</p><p>a</p><p>value.This is another value.</p>`